# In Jquery how do I check if none of the radiobuttons in a fieldset were checked?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, fieldset

I want to be able to find out if any of the radio buttons within a fieldset are checked in a form that contains multiple fieldsets, with each fieldset containing several radiobuttons.

I am currently able to check the number of radiobuttons checked and thus do validation upon submit by higlighting via css addClass the fieldset with zero radiobuttons checked.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ykK2s/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
var validate = function() {
    var count = 0;
    var fieldSetWithCheckboxes = $('fieldset').each(function(index, item) {
        if (($(item).find('input:radio').length > 0 && $(item).find('input:radio:checked').length === 0)) {
            $(item).addClass('alert');
            count++;
        }
        else{
             $(item).removeClass('alert');
        }
    });
    return (count > 0) ? false : true;
};


$('#multilistings').submit(function() {
    var result = validate();
    return result;
});​
```

checkout example here : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/Hk6eZ/)

**Note :** I updated the HTML with a dumb fieldset which does not have any checkboxes (which will not be highlighted)

**PS:** you should obviously use a different class to highlight the error :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle, I've updated your function http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ykK2s/9
This is only an example, you can customize it.